# Set root password in yocto kirkstone

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto

I tried to set my a password for the root by several approches. Nothing worked for me so far.
I added to the local.conf:

```
INHERIT += "extrausers"
EXTRA_USER_PARAMS = "usermod -P 'mypasswd' root;"
```

I also tried encrypting the password using "openssl passwd -6 -salt 12345  mypasswd":

```
INHERIT += "extrausers"
EXTRA_USER_PARAMS = "usermod -p '\$6\$12345\$CdkMCUqHIe6eWfFhMIppyUE/S.iLGe.PACPivJhw05ideCyogNpnVNDIBSQXhSruJxfZCasTi6YvFOrPgFvM7/' root;"
```

I tried both variants with and without EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "debug-tweaks". I also tried to set the password in sources/meta-qoriq/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-qoriq.inc which gets included in the kernel recipe "sources/meta-qoriq/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-qoriq_5.15.bb" like this "require linux-qoriq.inc".
With EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "debug-tweaks" set, no password was set and without it the password was wrong.
I also tried to edit the /ect/shadow file manually using the ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND. Therefore I added this lines in the sources/meta-qoriq/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-qoriq.inc file as it seems not to be possible to add a bash function to the local.conf file.

```
set_pw () {
    encrypted=$(openssl passwd -6 -salt 12345  mypasswd)
    sed -i "s/^root::/root:$encrypted:/" ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/shadow
}
ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "set_pw;"
```

This also did not work.
My board is a freescale LS1046ARDB. That's why im using the linux qoriq distribution from freescale.

**EDIT:**

Adding:

```
inherit fsl-utils
ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "set_pw;
```

to the .bb file of the image I'm building (sources/meta-qoriq/recipes-fsl/images/fsl-image-networking.bb) and adding the set_pw function to the sources/meta-qoriq/classes/fsl-utils.bbclass file worked for me. It was not possible to add the bash function to the fsl-image-networking.bb file directly.
But I'm still wondering why the

```
INHERIT += "extrausers"
EXTRA_USER_PARAMS = "usermod -P 'mypasswd' root;"
```

is not working. That's how it worked in some other posts like this one [How to set root password on Yocto / Poky image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274163/how-to-set-root-password-on-yocto-poky-image). Has the syntax of doing this changed in kirkstone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably a typo on the variable name? The correct is `EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS` (note the plural of users), see [the official documentation](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html?highlight=extra_users_params#term-EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS).

BTW, the best practices are discussed here: [How to securely update configuration for root password in yocto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54648532/how-to-securely-update-configuration-for-root-password-in-yocto/54651584#54651584)

Answer (score 1):

To answer:

> But I'm still wondering why the
>
> INHERIT += "extrausers"
>
> EXTRA_USER_PARAMS = "usermod -P 'mypasswd' root;"
>
> is not working. That's how it worked in some other posts like this one
> How to set root password on Yocto / Poky image?. Has the syntax of
> doing this changed in kirkstone?

As Tomas mentions, you need to use EXTRA_**USERS**_PARAMS.

I have used plain text passwords in the past on Yocto Sumo which worked. Now that I have moved to Kirkstone I've noticed it doesn't because [usermod](https://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod) has been changed to no longer accept plaintext password. You must pass it an encrypted password:

> -p, --password PASSWORD
>
> The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3).

Also note that **-p** is used instead of **-P**.

Yocto manual provides a good example of setting up a root password + new user.
[Example of using extrausers in Kirkstone](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/4.0.9/ref-manual/classes.html#extrausers-bbclass)